# List<string> summation

Tags: c#

I have a list of string with comma separated in each of them.
For eg:

```
abc,1,2,0,0,0,3,1,0
def,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,0
```

I would like to generate a summation of that two strings starting from index 1 of each string.
Output eg:

```
Output,3,2,1,0,0,4,1,
```

Below is my current code. But I am looking for shorter version of it.

```
    List<string> panelBinCodeStringList = new List<string>;
    //panelBinCodeStringList has more than 2 strings.
    List<int> totalTmpString = new List<int>();
    foreach (var binCodeString in panelBinCodeStringList)
    {
         var tmp = binCodeString.Substring(binCodeString.IndexOf(',') + 1).Split(',').ToList();
         for (int i =0; i < tmp.Count; i++)
         {
              if (totalTmpString.Count() <= i)
              {
                  totalTmpString.Add(Convert.ToInt16(tmp[i]));
              }
              else
              {
                   totalTmpString[i] += Convert.ToInt16(tmp[i]);
              }
         }
    }    
    totalFailedBinCodes = "Output," + string.Join(",", totalTmpString);
```

Comment: Overall: create an array to store the totals. For each: split by comma, parse as int, add each to the correct position in the array. Finally, combine the array using `string.Join` and output.

Answer (score 2):

Not very efficient, but working.

```
var abcTxt = "abc,1,2,0,0,0,3,1,0";
var defTxt = "def,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,0";

var abcList = abcTxt.Split(",").Skip(1).Select(int.Parse).ToList();
var defList = defTxt.Split(",").Skip(1).Select(int.Parse).ToList();

if (abcList.Count != defList.Count)
    throw new Exception("Collections do not have the same size");

var output = "Output";
for (var i = 0; i < abcList.Count; i++) output += "," + (abcList[i] + defList[i]);
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: You might want to add `var output = "Output," + string.Join(",", results);` to produce the final "result".

Comment: Good point updated my answert. Thx @Christian.K

Comment: Consider using a `StringBuilder` to construct the output string.

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] a =  abc.Split(",");
string[] d = def.Split(",");
String output = "Output";
for(int i= 1; i < a.Length; i++)
{
   output+= "," + (int.Parse(a[i]) + int.Parse(d[i]));
}
```

Comment: Initialize `output` with the string "Output", rather them empty, to produce what the OP wants.

Comment: Consider using a `StringBuilder` to construct the output string.

Answer (score 0):

Approach with `Linq.Zip()`

```
string s1 = "abc,1,2,0,0,0,3,1,0";
string s2 = "def,2,0,1,0,0,1,0,0";

Func<string, IEnumerable<int>> ToInt = x => x.Split(',').Skip(1).Select(int.Parse);
string res = "output," + string.Join(",", ToInt(s1).Zip(ToInt(s2),(x, y) => x+y));
```

Comment: I have actually more than 2 strings for my input. My input is in list<string>. I updated my post with my current current code. Was wondering if can use linq for that?